# How to run thucydides maven project in debug mode

Tags: eclipse, maven, debugging, automation, thucydides

I created  Thucydides project from thucydides-jbehave-plugin archetype.

I found that to run stories it can be used mvn command "verify thucydides:aggregate"
But what if I need to debug some step adding a breakpoint in appropriate line.
I tried to run "thucydides:aggregate -Dmaven.failsafe.debug verify" in eclipse maven configuration but got error "unable to install breakpoint in ..." and so failed to debug because class source code is not readable;

What is the correct command or other way to debug story with breakpoints?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

add parametes in 
Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=5005,suspend=y
and in you eclipse use remote debug.

You need start you application and when you see message that it wait connection, start remote debug.